# How can I force labels in `description` environment to stay within the margins?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, margins, enumerate, enumitem, description

The labels in `description` exceed the margin by default. I tried using `labelwidth=\widthof{Described Item} + 2.5\labelsep` and it works well. However, I would like `description` to handle the alignments automatically and not exceed the margins, just like `enumerate` and `itemize`.

The desired output is shown here, but I want it to be automatic rather than by manual adjustments of `labelwidth`

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{report}


\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}

\begin{document}


This is an example of a description list, which shows how elegant the \texttt{description} environment. Note how the option entry \texttt{labelwidth=$\backslash$widthof$\lbrace$Described Item$\rbrace$ + 2.5$\backslash$labelsep} aligns the description item to the paragraph

\begin{description}[labelwidth=\widthof{Described Item} + 2.5\labelsep, labelsep=5mm, align=right]
    \item[Described Item] The description
    \item[Described] The description
\end{description}


See how the description labels go beyond the margin:

\begin{description}[itemindent=0mm, labelsep=3mm, align=right]
    \item[Described Item] The description
    \item[Described] The description
\end{description}



\end{document}
```

Comment: I suspect they were not intended for use with [align right].  How is it supposed to place the first item aligned with all the other items when it deosn't know how wide each of them are?  You could try using a tabular, instead.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment `mydescription` runs the text twice.  The first run (inside a savebox) computes the needed `labelwidth`.  Warning, any global changes will leak out.  These can be disabled on a case-by-case basis.

Note that the width is measured using boldface font.

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}

%\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{environ}

\newlength{\descwidth}% reserve global name

\NewEnviron{mydescription}[1][]{% #1 = optional parmeters for description
  \global\descwidth=0pt
  \sbox1{\def\item[##1]{\sbox0{\textbf{##1}}%
      \ifdim\descwidth<\wd0 \global\descwidth=\wd0\fi}%
    \let\stepcounter=\relax% % disable global change macros
    \let\refstepcounter=\relax
    \BODY}% compute maximum width
  \description[labelwidth=\descwidth, align=right, #1]
    \BODY
  \enddescription}

\begin{document}

\begin{mydescription}[labelsep=5mm]
    \item[Described Item] The description\footnote{test}
    \item[Described] The description
\end{mydescription}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

This solution takes two runs and affects all `mydescription` environments.  It slowly increases the label width, then saves the final value to the aux file.  The next run reads this value at `\begin{document}`.

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}

%\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}

\newlength{\descwidth}
\setlength{\descwidth}{0pt}
\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{\write\@auxout{\string\global\string\descwidth=\the\descwidth}}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{mydescription}[1][]% #1 = optional parmeters for description
{\description[labelwidth=\descwidth, align=right, #1]
   \let\DefaultItem=\item
   \def\item[##1]{\sbox0{\textbf{##1}}%
     \ifdim\descwidth<\wd0 \global\descwidth=\wd0\fi
     \DefaultItem[##1]}%
}{\enddescription}

\begin{document}

\begin{mydescription}[labelsep=5mm]
    \item[Described Item] The description\footnote{test}
    \item[Described] The description
\end{mydescription}

\end{document}
```

Comment: very nice, except that if there is more than one description list on the same page, the indentation won't be the same unless the longest item in all the lists happens to be exactly the same length.  (apologies for being a troublemaker.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton - One could write the widths to the aux file and set a global max width when read.  I'll wait until the OP asks first.